# javascript throwing exception in internet explorer

Tags: javascript

below is my code,when i run this on internet explorer it throws exception of javascript on code which is highlighted with stars.
request you to please help me.

JavaScript critical error at line 200, column 5 in http://localhost:50317/js/functions.js\n\nSCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.slider1').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function (slider) {
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
    **})**;

  $('.slider2').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshow: false,
    animationLoop: false 
  });
});

});
```

Comment: You have put stars line 7

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma that shouldn't be there, and the final line is duplicated. This should be valid:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.slider1').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function (slider) {
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        } /* no comma here */
    });

    $('.slider2').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: false,
        animationLoop: false
    });
});
```